# Getting abstract class static field value

Tags: django

In my models I created an abstract base class to store information about last database modification. To do that I override *save* method where a static datetime field is updated with current time.
When I try to retrieve last modification time, a DeferredAttribute object is returned and the only way to fetch that value I have found yet is by calling that field from an instantiated object. However, in this way I won't be able to read the value if all objects in the database are deleted.

```
class Timestamp(models.Model):
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Timestamp.modified = timezone.now()
        super(Timestamp, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Node(Timestamp):
    latitude = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    longitude = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

# ...
# few more subclasses of Timestamp
```

Is there a way to get *modified* field value without having a derived class object? 
EDIT:
Looks like it's not possible to store data in static fields, thus the *modified* variable is never saved to the database. In such case I'll follow McAbra's reply.

Comment: There's nothing here that would give you a "deferred attribute". But you should be setting `self.modified` in your save method.

Comment: @Daniel Wouldn't it cause every object in the database to have its own modified field? Instead I want to have only one time stamp to store time of the latest change performed on whole database.

Comment: Now I really don't understand what you are trying to do. How could you keep a value without saving it to the database? What happens when you restart the server process?

Comment: I'm getting DeferredAttribute object when I try to read the value in Django shell (by simply typing 'Timestamp.modified' in the shell). However, if I firstly save a new Node object to the database then Timestamp.modified gives me datetime instead of deferred object.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply:

```
class Timestamp(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Node(Timestamp):
    latitude = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    longitude = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```